# How to allow double quotes in regular expression?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a textbox :

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="ValidateTitleCharacters" runat="server" 
    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9@+'.!#$',:;=/\(\),\-\s]{1,255}$"
    ControlToValidate="title" Text="You have entered a character(s) that is not allowed in the title."
    ErrorMessage="You have entered a character(s) that is not allowed in the title." />
```

I want to allow " character also. How can I modify the regular expression string???

I tried this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="ValidateTitleCharacters" runat="server" 
    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9@+'.!#$'\",:;=/(),\-\s]{1,255}$"
    ControlToValidate="title" Text="You have entered a character(s) that is not allowed in the title."
    ErrorMessage="You have entered a character(s) that is not allowed in the title." />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="ValidateTitleCharacters" runat="server" 
    Validat‌​ionExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9@+'.!#$',:;=/()(""),\-\s]{1,255}$"
    ControlToValidate="title" Text="You have entered a character(s) that is not allowed in the title."
    ErrorMessage="You have entered a character(s) that is not allowed in the title." />
```

Both attempts are breaking the string.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the quotes?

Comment: yes' but its showing errors. I mean its breaking the string.

Comment: Why do you limit the input to 255 characters?

Comment: Tried:ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9@+'.!#$'\",:;=/\(\),\-\s]{1,255}$"ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9@+'.!#$',:;=/\(\)(""),\-\s]{1,255}$"     I have that varchar(254) set in the Db so i hav limited the value

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the fragment you have posted, it appears that the regular expression is embedded in markup - this means you need to escape the double quote character as an HTML character entity.

Use `&quot;`:

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9@+'.!#$'&quot;,:;=/\(\),\-\s]{1,255}$"
```

The ASP.NET engine will translate the character entity to `"`.

Alternatively, set the `ValidationExpression` value in code behind (in `OnInit`, for example):

```
ValidateTitleCharacters.ValidationExpression = 
                                  "^[a-zA-Z0-9@+'.!#$'\",:;=/\(\),\-\s]{1,255}$";
```